# Did Jesus die on the Cross & was he a spirit or not?

Tags: luke, contradiction

From the evidence it appears that Jesus did not die on the cross based on the below.

Rom 6:9 & 1 Pete 3:18 imply Jesus died and raised as a spirit.  Yet Luke 24:39 Jesus is not a spirit.  Hosea 6:6 - For I desire mercy, not sacrifice / Matthew 9:13 & 12:7 But go and learn what this means: ‘I desire mercy, not sacrifice /
supported by Hebrew 5:7.  Importantly **Deuteronomy 21:22-23** a person hung is cursed by God

**does this indicate that Jesus did not die on the Cross**  No one actually evidence Jesus die - Matthew 26:56.

**Deuteronomy 21:22-23**
22 If someone guilty of a capital offense is put to death and their body is exposed on a pole, 23 you must not leave the body hanging on the pole overnight. Be sure to bury it that same day, because anyone who is hung on a pole is under God’s curse. You must not desecrate the land the Lord your God is giving you as an inheritance.

Luke 24:39 - "Behold my hands and my feet, that it is I myself: handle me, and see; for a spirit hath not flesh and bones, as ye see me have".

Hebrews 5:7
Who in the days of his flesh, with a strong cry and tears, offering up prayers and supplications to him that was able to save him from death, was heard for his reverence.

Rom 6:9 knowing that Christ, having been raised from the dead, is never to die again; death no longer is master over Him.

1 Pet 3:18 ‘For Christ also died for sins once for all… so that He might bring us to God, having been put to death in the flesh, but made alive in the spirit’

Comment: Jesus said he was not a spirit and offered his hands and feet - indicating that he meant he was not a _disembodied spirit_ or a mere apparition. But, risen from the dead, his body was clearly enlivened by his own spirit. I do not see why you question Jesus being alive or dead. The question lacks clarity and detail.

Comment: Your edit, to my mind, has resulted in even less clarity. I fail to understand what point you are making regarding the Deuteronomy text. This is complete confusion.

Comment: @NigelJ I have amended to add more context.  your comments appear to be opinion rather not fact. No one witnessed Jesus death - Only 'Paul' that makes new claims, but these would be contradiction of other verses.

Comment: @NigelJ - amended again slightly - the point is it appears that Jesus did not die on the cross.  Deuteronomy implies that any hung on the cross / pole is cursed - therefore implying that Jesus did not die on the cross.  Are you confused or have no answer?

Comment: _Christ hath redeemed us from the curse of the law, **being made a curse for us** : for it is written, Cursed is every one that hangeth on a tree:_ Galatians 3:13.

Comment: The soldiers came to break Jesus' legs in order to speed His death so that he would not hang there into the Sabbath and found that they did not need to because he was already dead.  Yes, He died on the cross.

Comment: @anothertheory - you might consider changing name - it is unproductive - we don't need more theories - plenty of those already! We need biblical truth to oppose the nonsense of other sources. PS, don't call yourself 'biblical truth' either! lol

Comment: @NigelJ- Great last point of yours. Mine is the second acknowledgement there.

Comment: @anothertheory- As already pointed out: Soldiers came to break the legs of the "fleshly" Jesus but found him already dead, but just to confirm, a spear was then thrust into his side, which was deep enough to extract water as well as blood. So, if he wasn't "physically" dead already, he evidently was after the spear thrust. When he rose from death and ascended into heaven, then he would have to have been in a "spiritual' state, as flesh & blood cannot enter heaven, 1 Cor, 15:50

Comment: @OldeEnglish To be even clearer, It is more specifically defined as a spiritual **body** now imperishable -  1 Cor. 15:42-44.  'Flesh and blood' evokes the corruption inherited from Adam but does not negate the real physicality of Christ's resurrected body.

Comment: @MikeBorden-Thank you for pointing out those other verses and I agree with your understanding to a point. I am not, however, an advocate for the "physical/fleshly" resurrection of Christ, even as portrayed before doubting Thomas. Whenever "spiritual" beings/angelic messengers of God appeared before men (take Lot for instance) they seemed outwardly physical, in every aspect, but were still ethereal. In Jude 6 & 7 we read about the demonic angels that temporarily took on the "physical" in no uncertain terms, but reverted back to the "spiritual" once the "Flood" came. Puzzling one for sure....

Answer (score 2):

**Death of Jesus**

First, there is plenty of evidence that Jesus actually died and was then miraculously came back to life.  Here is a sample.

There are several records that Jesus' death would happen.

- Matt 16:21 - and that he must be killed and on the third day be raised to life.
- Matt 17:23 - They will kill him, and on the third day he will be raised to life.
- Matt 20:19 - and will hand him over to the Gentiles to be mocked and flogged and crucified. On the third day he will be raised to life!
- Mark 9:31 - They will kill him, but on the third day he will come back to life.
- Mark 10:34 - who will mock him and spit on him, flog him and kill him. Three days later he will rise.
- Luke 18:33 - they will flog him and kill him. On the third day he will rise again.
- Luke 9:22 - The Son of Man must suffer many things and be rejected by the elders, the chief priests and the teachers of the law, and he must be killed and on the third day be raised to life.

The eye-witness accounts of Jesus' death:

- Matt 27:50 - "... Jesus … yielded up the/his spirit", or, he "breathed his last". That is, he stopped breathing and died. The guarding centurion also observed the death, v51.
- Mark 15:37 - " … Jesus … expired". That is, He stopped breathing and died. The guarding centurion also observed the death, v38.
- Mark 15:44 - When Joseph of Arimathea asked Pilate for the body of Jesus, Pilate was surprised he was already dead, so he asked a centurion to check that Jesus was dead. The centurion confirmed it so Pilate released the body to Joseph. A Roman centurion is a trained killer and an expert in telling if someone is dead.
- Luke 23:46 - " … expired". That is, He stopped breathing and died. The guarding centurion also observed the death, v47.
- John 19:30 - "He [Jesus] said, 'It is finished!' And he bowed his head and gave up his spirit." That is, He stopped breathing and died.
- John 19:33 - the soldiers did not break Jesus' legs because he was already dead. (Roman soldiers were trained killers and knew how to tell if someone was alive or dead!)
- John 19:34 - just to be absolutely sure, one Roman soldier took a spear and pierced his side - this would have been a trust of the spear up under the rub cage into the heart. If Jesus were not dead before he would certainly have been dead afterward. As a result, a mixture of blood and water emerged suggesting that he really was dead indeed!
- John 19:35 - the apostle John says he witnessed these things personally and testifies that these facts are correct.

Some have suggested that there were no disciples and very few people who actually saw the death of Jesus but that is not true. All Roman crucifixions were done to achieve two objectives - to completely humiliate the victim and to provide some cheap ghoulish entertainment for the masses - thus all crucifixions were attended by crowds (Luke 23:48).
It is also said that all the disciples deserted him in the garden of Gethsemane (Matt 26:56) but Peter (and some others) followed at a distance to observe the trials ((Matt 26:58). Specifically, we know that the following named people observed the death of Jesus:

- Simon of Cyrene, another disciple, who carried the cross Matt 27:32, Luke 23:26.
- Joseph of Arimathea who asked Pilate for the body Luke 23:50-53.
- Nicodemus who visited Jesus by night John 19:39
- Cleopas and his friend Luke 24:13-21 who were travelling to Emmaus on Sunday.
- Many women and others associated with Jesus (Luke 23:49) such as Mary the mother of Jesus, Mary's sister Martha, Mary Magdalene, Mary the mother of James and Joses, Salome, Mary the wife of Cleopas, Matt 27:55, 56, Mark 15:40, John 19:25. This also included (at least) John as recorded in John 19:26, 27.
- It is also recorded that many of these same people accompanied the dead body to the tomb to see where it was laid so that could embalm the body on Sunday morning. Matt 27:61, 28:1, Mark 15:47, 16:1, Luke 23:55, 24:10, John 20:1.
- One of the soldiers, specifically a centurion observed Jesus' death and was so moved that he gave praise to the Jewish God of heaven Matt 27:54, Luke 23:47. Another pierced him with a spear to ensure His death and a soldier also witnessed the fact to Pilate Mark 15:44, 45.
- Many of the Jewish leaders, including the chief priests, observed the crucifixion and death to ensure that Jesus died and that their troublesome citizen was finally disposed of. Matt 27:41-43, Mark 15:31
  There are numerous other passages that discuss the death of Jesus.
- Luke 24:46 - This is what is written: The Messiah will suffer and rise from the dead on the third day
- 1 Cor 15:3, 4 - … that Christ died for our sins according to the Scriptures, that he was buried, that he was raised on the third day
- Acts 10:40 - God raised him from the dead on the third day and caused him to be seen.
- Acts 13:30 - But God raised him up from the dead the third day
  There is much evidence that Jesus actually died, not only from his friends the disciples but from Roman soldiers as well; that is, both sympathetic and antagonistic witnesses. This is very compelling and voluminous evidence.

There is also some important indirect evidence that Jesus was known by everyone in Jerusalem, including the chief priests and Roman authorities, to have died.

- The chief priests were worried that the disciples would come to try and steal the dead body so they posted a Roman guard to protect it, and on the Sabbath as well!! Matt 27:62-66.
- The Roman soldiers guarding the tomb witnessed the resurrection but the chief priests were so embarrassed by this they bribed the soldiers to say (in spite of dire consequences for soldiers sleeping on duty) that the (dead) body of Jesus was stolen while they slept!! Matt 28:11-15. This possibly even involved some bribes for Pilate (v14).
- Despite the report of some, many of the disciples could not believe that Jesus was raised for the dead and were very frightened; Luke 24:36-43, John 20:11, 19, 20, 24-29.
  In fact, the doctrine of Jesus’ humanity is so important that anyone who denies it is called antichrist! 1 John 4:3, 2 John 7.

**Jesus' Resurrection**

Unlike Jesus’ death, there were no witnesses to His resurrection, only the fact that three days after dying He was observed to be living.  These include:

- The soldiers guarding the tomb, Matt 28:1-4, 11-15.
- Mary Magdalene (a woman of questionable integrity) was the first to see the empty tomb and later talk with Jesus at the tomb, John 20:1, 10-18, Mark 16:9-11.  Several other women also saw the empty tomb, Luke 24:1-12, Matt 28:1, 5-8, Mark 16:1-8.
- Two men, Cleopas and another on the Road to Emmaus, Luke 24:13-35, Mark 16:12, 13.
- Jesus’ disciples in the upper room on that first Sunday evening, John 20:19-23, Matt 28:9, 10.
- The disciples including doubting Thomas (a week later), John 20:24-31, Luke 24:36-49, Mark 16:14.
- Peter and other disciples by the lake, John 21, 1 Cor 15:5.
- More than 500 people/witnesses, including James, 1 Cor 15:6, 7.
- The disciples at Jesus ascension, Acts 1:3-11, Luke 24:51-53, Matt 28:16-20, Mark 16:15-18.
- The apostle Paul, 1 Cor 15:8.

There is much indirect evidence of the factual nature of Jesus death (as listed above) and resurrection including:

- Women, including Mary Magdalene, were the first to witness to the resurrection.  If the disciples had wanted to invent this story they would have placed men as the primary witnesses.
- The soldiers guarding the tomb readily testified to Jesus’ resurrection – despite the fact that this made them liable to execution for failing on duty.
- The Jewish leaders knew that Jesus had risen because they bribed the soldiers and bribed Pilate to say that Jesus’ body was simply stolen, Matt 28:13-15.
- Later, the disciples were constantly talking about the death and resurrection of Jesus (Acts 2:32, 3:26, 4:10, 5:30, 10:40, 13:30, 34, 17:31, Rom 1:4, 4:24, 8:11, 10:9, 1 Cor 6:14, 15:4, 2 Cor 4:14, Gal 1:1, Col 2:20, 1 Thess 1:10, 2 Tim 2:8, Heb 13:20, 1 Peter 1:3, etc.)  All the disciples were killed as martyrs except John (they tried several times to kill him).  This is not a story they would invent and then die for a fabricated lie.
- The story of Jesus’ resurrection does not have any hallmarks of a fabricated story.  If it had been invented it would involve a victorious political Messiah against Roman oppressors, not a dead hero!  It would also NOT include a death in the most ignominious way by Roman oppressors such a crucifixion.
- Many of the witnesses to the resurrection included almost all antagonistic people such as Pilate, the soldiers, the Jewish leaders and even the disciples themselves who did not believe it at first.

**CONCLUSION**

There is no doubt that the Gospels and the entire NT corpus is based upon the actual death and resurrection of Jesus, the Son of God.

Further, there is nothing in the NT (that I can find) suggesting that "Jesus is spirit" and so the basis of the OP is mystifying.  Jesus' death and resurrection is to (among other things) provide irrefutable proof of His humanity.  This says nothing about Jesus divinity or otherwise - THAT is another topic entirely.

Suffice to say here that whether we accept Jesus as divine or not, the NT says He died and rose again on the third day.  If we accept that Jesus was divine, then what happened to Jesus' divinity while he died is a great mystery that this questions does not begin to answer and would be the potential topic of another post.  (This one is already too long.)

Comment: @Dottard-I just read this, after I had commented above. Truly amazing answer, which should leave no doubt in anyone's mind as to Jesus' death. As to the aspect of Jesus' divinity....I'm not sure that he was divine while in the "flesh", but certainly was before and after when in the "spirit".

Answer (score 1):

Yeshua (Jesus) of Nazareth left His Body on the Cross in fulfillment of Deuteronomy 21:22-23, and Numbers 21:8-9. * Yeshua could not have been spiritually dead in regards to His teaching in [Mark 12:26-27].

- In [John 3] Yeshua tells Nicodemus that His cursed body will be like the Nehushtan ( נְחֻשְׁתָּֽן) referencing 2 Kings 18:4  / Numbers 21:8-9 : "Just as Moses lifted up the snake in the wilderness, so the Son of Man must be lifted up, that everyone who believes may have eternal life in him."

Yeshua (Jesus) of Nazareth makes 3-statements while on the Cross to allude to His soul's salvation after leaving the dust of His cursed body.

1. Yeshua sings [Psalm 22] in Matthew 27:46 as a fulfilled prophecy about Himself. - When we read [Psalm 22:21] the prophecy alludes to YHVH saving Yeshua's soul, before the impact of the sword from the Centurion. - This indicates Yeshua's soul left His body.
2. On the Cross, Yeshua was crucified next to a repentant criminal who is told by the Messiah in Luke 23:43 "Truly I tell you, today you will be with me in paradise.” - Alluding to their souls transition to Heaven that day.
3. Yeshua leaves His body on the Cross in Luke 23:46 : 'Jesus called out with a loud voice, “Father, into your hands I commit my spirit." When he had said this, he breathed his last.'

Although all earthly bodies are made from dust which is already dead, Yeshua's life restores Yisraelites' desire to live in a devoted relationship with their Creator YHVH described in [Mark 12] by Yeshua: "He is not the God of the dead, but of the living."

Comment: the way i read this is - that if you die you become a spirit and cannot die again - Rom 6:9, yet in Luke Jesus clearly implies that he is not a spirit and eats, therefore he did not die on the cross.  Deuteronomy 21:22-23 a person hung is cursed by God - why would Jesus be cursed by God no evidence to support this or that he died on the cross for us.

Comment: In context to the Gospel accounts, Spiritual Death is the worship of idols or deified humans like Caesar. Yeshua did not worship idols or images of men during His ministry. Salvation lives at the right hand of the Father YHVH.

Comment: @ctaylorgraphics- Your answer didn't deserve the down vote, so I have given you an up vote. Not sure that I entirely agree with you on "Point 2" though. Paradise for the criminal I believe was merely "assured" on that day.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, Jesus died on the cross.** Only a man can die - God cannot. Jesus was a man as testified by himself and his closest friends and disciples/apostles(Rom 5:15, Acts 2:22, John 8:40, 1 Tim 2:5).

He came to us as the son of God - not God, but born of the flesh through Mary and of the power of God through His Spirit. "Made like us in every way" Heb 2:17.

**Was Jesus spirit?**

> See my hands and my feet, that it is I myself. Touch me, and see. For **a spirit does not have flesh and bones** as you see that I have.” Luke 24:39

He was not immortal until he was raised by his Father - then, and only then, was he living by spirit in which he could no longer die.

> ...Christ, having been raised from the dead, is never to die again; death no longer is master over him. Rom 6:9 NASB

> ...Death no longer rules over him BLB

*If* Jesus is God, then we must explain how Jesus was 'mastered or ruled by death'. This could never apply to God. Only the man Jesus, who was *born in the flesh* and *raised in the spirit* (1 Pet 3:18, John 5:26) could be so mastered - meaning he was mortal and subject to death.

He prayed to God who could *save him from death* - what death? The death he would die eternally if he had sinned - he could not be raised again (Heb 5:7). Like us, death is permanent unless we are saved, cleansed, redeemed by the 'perfect' sacrifice of another.

Jesus now has a spirit life and the Father has enabled Jesus to also *give* the spirit of life in the resurrection. 2 Cor 3:17, Acts 2:33

1 Cor 15 explains the process of flesh to spirit, mortal to immortal, of which Jesus was the first-fruit of that process Col 1:15-18

We must not confuse a 'spirit being' (angel, God) with a 'human being' who is now 'spirit'. Raised, changed/transformed humans will still be humans - as Jesus now is - but glorified and having eternal life too (which the second death has no power over).

Comment: @user48152-Not sure of the meaning of your second to last sentence. Don't you mean, "....with a 'human being' that is now infused with spirit (active force of God & Jesus), but still human as Jesus, was (not, is)". Also, humility does not come easy to you I've noticed, these last few months. I could however, not find fault with your narrative before the last 2 sentences and almost reversed your down vote too.

Comment: @OldeEnglish fair point, I stand corrected - got a bit zealous! To be clear - Jesus is still human, but with spirit 'infused' if you like. The same as we will be when changed. He's the firstborn - of many brethren!

Comment: @user48152- There you go again: Jesus "is", instead of "was". When Jesus comes again, it will not be as Jesus "per se". He will be his "spiritual" self, as will all the army of angels who will accompany him. His "humanity" died on the cross, never to be taken up again. " Changed!!"...There will be a minority that will be "transfigured" from the "earthly" into the "spiritual" in order to be able to gain access to heaven and then there will be others (Great Multitude), that go through the "GT", who are not called to heaven (myself included) but become, at least, immortal, resurrected ones also.

Comment: @OldeEnglish no I meant every word just as writ. Looks like a new Q coming from you? I look forward to it. thx for yr comments. This one is about to be closed anyway!

Comment: @user48152-You should see my Q & A: "In Matt, 6:10, it is implied that the kingdom to come, will be on earth....". See also my answer and comments to Karma's Q: "Who are the "Great Multitude" in Rev, 7:9"

Comment: Thank you for your answers & comments – A detailed response would be too long such as who actually witnessed & what and who wrote these accounts and the various accounts at the tomb etc.. so I will respond as short as possible.  You have not taken into account / responded to the verses in the question.  luke 20:35-36 a resurrected body can not die again and are like the angels (spirits). Rom 6:9 & 1 Pete 3:18 implies Jesus died and was raised as a spirit. Luke 39-43 - why did Jesus ask them to touch as a spirit has no flesh and bones as you see me have & eat - this implies he was not a spirit.

Comment: John 19:321-35 is this from John or an unknown person.  As to pierced his side, this could be to stop the blood from clotting (actually helping).  Why is Jesus disguised as a Gardner, why say 'touch me not' Mark 16:11  hear Jesus was ALIVE not spirit.  Luke 24:30 – as he sat eating (again eating) Luke 24:23 the angels said Jesus was alive.  Are the versus inconsistent?